# UWP10 ViewModel property is null

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, mvvmcross

I am trying to build an mvvm app using mvvmcross. When I start the app a null reference exception occurs.

this is my codebehind file which uses MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views.

```
 public sealed partial class MainView : MvxWindowsPage
{
    public MainView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MainViewModel = (MainViewModel)ViewModel;            
    }

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

    public PlayersViewModel PlayersViewModel { get; set; } = Mvx.IocConstruct<PlayersViewModel>();
}
```

This is my app.cs file.

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        RegisterAppStart<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

When I set an break point at MainViewModel = (MainViewModel)ViewModel; the break point is hit and I can see that the ViewModel property is null. what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewModel` property is not yet initialized in the constructor. That's why its value is still `null`.

You will need to move the assignment to a different method that gets called later, e.g. `OnNavigatedTo`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    MainViewModel = (MainViewModel)ViewModel;
}
```

Even better, instead of assigning `ViewModel` to your own auto implemented property, rather have the `MainViewModel` getter perform the cast. Then you don't even need to do the assignment:

```
public MainViewModel MainViewModel => (MainViewModel)ViewModel;
```

Unfortunatelly UWP doesn't support generic base classes in XAML, otherwise you could use `MvxWindowsPage<MainViewModel>` as the base page, not needing to do the cast at all.